# "Recursive" Wildcard DNS for Amazon Route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, internal-dns, amazon-route53

The title of the question might be misleading because I'm not an expert and I'm trying to learn the proper terminology.  That being said, I'm wondering if it's possible to setup a wildcard DNS record for any number of dot separation in domain names and have them all point to the network root.  This is for WordPress multisite, users will have the option of choosing a mapped domain name, I want to configure my DNS so that both `mysite.co.uk.network.com` and `mysite.com.network.com` are valid (I realize this is a but ugly, but WordPress multisite requires that each site have a unique `site_url` and I'd prefer to preserve the period-delimited appearance if it's possible).

Comment: Similar question - seems like maybe this is not possible? http://serverfault.com/questions/546554/wildcard-dns-like-test-example-com?rq=1

Comment: Is `network.com` the domain you've purchased in this example? And are you're saying you want to setup a wild card fro `mysite.co.uk` and `mysite.com`?

Comment: I want both `mysite.co.uk.network.com` and `mysite.com.network.com` to be valid.  Ugly I know, but the alternative is `mysitecomuk.network.com`.